Strange updating JSS styles
There is project with Preact + JSS. The case is when i try to update attached styles my dynamic styles lost those CSS properties that contains functions as a value. The most interesting here the properties update excellently when they are written in kebab case.
Preact
const sheet = jss.createStyleSheet(styles, { link: true });

  sheet.attach();

  effect(() => {
    sheet.update({ theme: GlobalScheme.value.HintPreview });
  });

styles
  '&:before, &:after': {
      position: 'absolute',
      content: '""',
      height: 13,
      width: 2,
      borderRadius: '25%',
      backgroundColor: ({ theme }: any) => theme.color,
    },

But it works if background color properties is written like this background-color;
This is a really strange behavior because the borderRadius property in instance above works perfectly in any cases.
The effect is the signal from the preact library.
I can accept that i am missing something, but despite the JSS library has a specification, there are not any mentions about this case.
